# How to force rtl support for a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I've disabled and forced my application to not support rtl . Because it made lots of problems of views and layouts , this is my manifest code:

```
<application
    android:name="ir.dizbon.persiandesigners.ParseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl">
```

in one layout I add this code :

```
 android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

When I remove the manifest code ,the layout change the direction and works fine but I can't remove manifest codes .

I tried to change the direction pragmatically:

```
pass_l.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

it doesn't work either .

How can I make my view to support rtl and get rtl ?

Comment: did you want to work both of rtl and ltr?

Comment: Did you find solution to problem, apart from creating new layout

Answer (score -1):

You can create different layout in android studio to support rtl.
Right click layout -> New -> Layout Resource File -> then choose Layout Direction Qualifier.
[image]

Comment: thanks for reply , I don't want to support rtl in my layout , I want to force my view to gets rtl in any language